# generate random long user ID

Tags: java, random, statistics, long-integer, stochastic

I am writing an android app giving each client a long user ID through this formula:

`long userID = (long) (Math.random() * 2 * Long.MAX_VALUE - Long.MAX_VALUE);`

Am I utilizing MAX_VALUE correctly i.e. taking advantage of every possible long value?

What are my chances of having two duplicate user IDs with 10k, 100k or 1m users? How could I calculate this?

Comment: You should probably use new Random().nextLong(); instead...

Comment: You can expect first duplicates after using half of all possible values (assuming you have decent random algorithm) so in your case it might be `2^34` values. That's why it is better to use UUID (128bit) as recommended below. Alternatively you can use conflict-free (no duplicates guaranteed) long IDs e.g. Twitter Flake Id generator.

Comment: thanks tom, that's what i was wondering.
I don't expect to have that many users, so in my case i think it's safe enough to use a 128bit random uuid. I'll write a todo so at a later stage i'm going to let my server check for duplicate users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of either one of those mentioned below:

1. Instead of using the random to get a long user id, use current date and time expressed in milliseconds.
2. Use a Random UUID

Comment: Or use both (timestamp + random). This will make the conflict very unlikely

Comment: +1 for date and time since that's guaranteed to not give duplicates. It will however introduce personalization to the user ID to some degree.

Comment: thanks for the tip with uuid, that really seems to be what i'm looking for.
So i should use a 128 bit random uuid as well as a 64 bit timestamp at the same time?

Comment: Well, do you really need 128 bit unique ID or will the 64 suffice?

Comment: I think even 64bit should suffice - 
but I wouldn't use an ID only based on time, i think it's unsafer than a random 64bit value.

Comment: If you make the system sleep for one millisecond before generating the  unique id and if you make sure the systems clock is synchronized with the same server, all the time, it should be no problem.

I am not sure, but also RandomUUID is based on time, in some manner. 

Now, the big question is: what do you want to use the unique id for?

Comment: It's just for identifying the user's data when syncing, the application is a simple android game, so no big security threats if a duplicate ID really should occur. If I'm ever going to write something that really requires 100% uniqueness, i'll come back to your tip. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/bigfatsea/SUID Simple Unique Identifier

You may expect duplicated ids on same instance 136 years later, good enough for medium-small projects.

Example:

```
long id = SUID.id().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a Random UUID using `randomUUID()`

[documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29)